# Trying to fix a method that gives me back the account(s) in the list that have the max value (600)

Tags: java, arrays, object

Trying to fix some code I'm having trouble with, it's giving me an unwanted account object in the array.

```
public static ArrayList<Account> maxBalanceAccounts(ArrayList<Account> accounts){
        ArrayList<Account> maxBalanceAccounts = new ArrayList<>();
        double max = 0;
        for(Account account : accounts){
            if(account.getBalance()>=max){
                max = account.balance;
                maxBalanceAccounts.add(account);
            }
        }
        return maxBalanceAccounts;
    }
```

The outcome is [Checking{accountNumber=1, balance=200.0}, Savings{accountNumber=2, balance=600.0}, Savings{accountNumber=4, balance=600.0}]
I want to remove the account with 200.0.

Comment: So, change `double max = 0;` to `final double max = 600.00;` and delete the `max = account.balance;` line.

Comment: 600 is just an example from the OPs test data, not the value they want to use

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrong because it saves any account that is the max so far.  The easiest way is to have two passes.

```
  public static ArrayList<Account> maxBalanceAccounts(ArrayList<Account> accounts) {
        // Find maximum balance of all accounts
        double max = 0;
        for (Account account : accounts) {
            if (account.getBalance() >= max) {
                max = account.balance;
            }
        }
        // Select accounts whose balance is maximal
        ArrayList<Account> maxBalanceAccounts = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Account account : accounts) {
            if (account.getBalance() >= max) {
                maxBalanceAccounts.add(account);
            }
        }
        return maxBalanceAccounts;
    }
```

There are other ways to express this, but this seems to be closest to your original formulation, and is conceptually quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

This returns an ArrayList of the accounts that are equal to or more than the max value.

```
public static ArrayList<Account> maxBalanceAccounts(ArrayList<Account> accounts) {
    ArrayList<Account> correctAccounts = new ArrayList<>();
    double max = 600.0;
    for (Account selected: accounts){
        if(selected.getBalance() >= max){
            correctAccounts.add(selected);
        }
    }
    return correctAccounts;
}
```

Additionally, to make your code easier to modify in the future, you should make max either an attribute within class Account or a parameter of maxBalanceAccounts.